# Check workings for Trig Equation $\sin2x = 0.5, 0^{\circ}\le x \le 360^{\circ}$

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve  $\sin2x = 0.5, 0^{\circ}\le x \le 360^{\circ}$

rearrange to

$2x = \sin^{-1}0.5$

$2x = 30^{\circ}$

$x = 15^{\circ}$

As this is sine, the values are in the first and second quadrant so,

$x = 15^{\circ}$

or

$x = 180^{\circ} -15^{\circ} = 165^{\circ}$

Comment: 30°　150°　390°　510°　each half.

Comment: How to solve a Trigonometric Equation  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Krukrx6TR5I&nohtml5=False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \sin 2x = \frac 12$$
$$2x=(-1)^k \frac{\pi}{6}+\pi k, k \in \mathbb Z$$
$$x=(-1)^k \frac{\pi}{12}+\frac{\pi k}{2}, k \in \mathbb Z$$
$$x \in \left\{\frac{\pi}{12}=15^{\circ} , \frac{5\pi}{12}=75^{\circ}, \frac{13\pi}{12}=195^{\circ}, \frac{17\pi}{12}=255^{\circ}\right\}$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand the last line of this answer.

Comment: where are $\pi, 5\pi$ etc. coming from?$

Comment: @dagda1: $k=0,1,2,3$

Comment: I understand where 15 comes from but not75, 195 or 255

Comment: 1/2-1/12,  1/2+1/12,  3/2-1/12 or  15 multiple 5 ,13 ,17

Comment: @TakahiroWaki is there a name did this so I can google about it?